# Fisherian and frequentist approaches

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I'm currently learning fundamentals of statistical inference. These concepts are of paramount importance as written in the textbook. However, I'm still confused about some details related it.

It says frequentist approaches is a sort of 'development' from the Fisherian approach, which focus on the idea of repeated sampling and likelihood. However, I'm still unclear about what are the exact characteristics of frequentist approach that makes it stand out as a separate methodology.

It would be great if there can be an example that illustrates a situation that the Fisherian and frequentist approach would arrive to different conclusion on the same statistical problem.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: An attempt at distinguishing between the Fisher approach and the Neyman-Pearson approach was described in [an article by Erich Lehmann](https://errorstatistics.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/lehmann_1-theory-or-2.pdf).  It gives three explicit examples.  One issue is that modern applied frequentist statistics as taught to researchers who are not statisticians tends to confuse the two and so draw conclusions (using the language of one but the methods of the other) that neither approach really justifies.